# subtract one list from another in unity c#

Tags: c#, android, linq, list, unity-game-engine

How can I subtract List **"firstList"** from List **"secondList"** in unity c#. I have found answers to do this with **LINQ** and **HashSet** but after reading [this](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/to-linq-or-not-to-linq.223887/) and [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/11610/using-hashset-in-unity.html) I am very doubtful to use those. Please point me in right direction because I have to deploy my game on IOS and Android both.

Comment: So, you want to keep items from the first list that aren't inside the second list? Do your objects in list have Id? What about simple for loop solution with checking inside? You could also give us some code.

Comment: I am generating two random lists of string. Suppose in first I have {"F", "G", "M", "T", "M", "F"} and in second I have {"F", "H", "G", "M", "Z",  "T"}. Now with these two I want a third list which should be from extra characters from second list which is not present in first list. So the third list should contain {"H", "z"} only. My generated list has somewhere around 30 character in each list, so running a loop might not be performance efficient.

Comment: for (int i=0; i<SecondList.Count; i++) {
  if(!firstList.Contains(SecondList[i]))
   thirdList.Add(SecondList[i]);
}  right now I am doing it like this.

Comment: Well, looks to me like it should be working.

Comment: well I am not sure if this is the optimized way of coding for mobile platform because of performance issues.And since my list is big I am looking for another way to do it more efficiently.

Comment: I'm not sure how often do you change items in that filter list. Dictionary or HashSet will be faster than list when used for searching values. Also, LINQ wouldn't speed up things, it would actually slow it down.

Answer (score 1):

"The posts you link to are talking about C#2.0, which does not support LINQ"

That... may not be entirely relevant, as C# version and .NET version is not necessarily a 1:1 match.

That said, Unity (actually Mono) definitely supports LINQ.

Still, LINQ basically just generates code and delegates it hides, while the actual implementation (IL) is still most likely simply loops (over loops). So syntactic sugar aside, the question rather is is which of the sets are larger (if you care about efficiency) and probably use that as the outer loop.

++luck;

Comment: my second loop is larger. yes you are right unity supports LINQ. Bus list sorting have some problem on IOS and it usually breaks with errors. And they are talking about this in the post.

Comment: LINQ is not always the fastest/most efficient though.  Depends on scenario, .NET version etc.